# Select2 in bootstrap not working properly jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am working with select2 library, and have a big problem. I start to use bootstrap, and for some reason select2 is not working properly ex:

As you can see it doesn't want to open, after opening, it selects all items on mouseover, and it is not possible to close.

Code in [jsFidldle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/wr2tqn9L/37/).

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.form-control').select2({
        dropdownParent: $(this).find('.modal-body'),
        theme: 'bootstrap',
    });
});
```

Library which i use:

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap-5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/js/Library/Select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/js/Library/Select2/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/Library/Select2/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Library/Select2/select2.full.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Library/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you use select2 full and select2 min ?

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work proprely

Comment: @SimoneRossaini in jsfiddle it's dont want to work properly

Comment: Your GIF have an input with 100% width, if you see your fiddle that doesn't have a good width.

Comment: Your `http://hanse-bahn-stralsund.de/css/bootstrap-4/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` is not https in your fiddle

Comment: Oh now i see what you did, you copy code from console google true?

Comment: Your *updated* fiddle doesn't demonstrate the problem - missing mouse over css, but does a single click.   Can you include the code here, in a snippet rather than in a fiddle with uneditable resource urls

Comment: Use simple html don't use select2 parameters, the plugin with add it own

Comment: For the css, you've included select2.bootstrap *for bootstrap 3* - but you're using bootstrap 5.  Bootstrap css classes change dramatically with each version.

Comment: Select2 work with bootstrap 4 / 3, [bootstrap 4 select2](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme)

Comment: @freedomn-m but as i can see it's not clases, because first of all it's don't want to open and scroll, and auto selecting each hover element

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i try to use Bootstrap 4 the same result

Comment: please provide a complete snippet with bootstrap 4 **without** select2 parameters in the html.

Comment: Or the opposite of @SimoneRossaini 's suggestion - a complete snippet of select2 **without** bootstrap - showing it working as you'd expect.   (eg the 'style=width:100%' is on the wrong DOM element)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini in case if just delete bootstrap library, it's work the same

Comment: To use `theme:bootstrap` you need a *matching* theme.  Your includes are difficult to see in the fiddle (once again: please include in a snippet here) - eg you have 4.1.0 css, 4.1.0 js *then also* 4.0.0 js (for select2).  Then you have bootstrap 4 js *and* bootstrap 5js+css.    Then you have a select2-bootstrap-theme for **select2 v3**.   Using all the same versions and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/c6equsjg/